# AngularJS 2 way Data Binding not working?

Tags: angular

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>TheNetNinja Angular Playlist</title>
    <link href="content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" ng-model="favMeat" placeholder="enter your fav meat" />
    <p>Your fav meat is: {{ favMeat }} </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The text box and the words below it are showing up, but the 'favMeat' value is not showing up when I type in the text box. I'm also running this on a local server built into the atom text editor. I would guess it has something to do with my src files? If I comment out the second src it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no angularjs2 , its just angular 1.x or angular 2/4/5/6.

Just remove the duplicate reference to **`angular.js`**

Anyhow the above code works,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>TheNetNinja Angular Playlist</title>
    <link href="content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" ng-model="favMeat" placeholder="enter your fav meat" />
    <p>Your fav meat is: {{ favMeat }} </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works only if I take all of the other text out of the p tag and just have the variable.

Comment: did you have a look at the demo?

Comment: Yeah it works in the demo. Maybe it's my text editor.

Comment: it does not have anything to do with the editor i guess